# authorizing directory only when running on localhost

Tags: asp.net

I have this in the `web.config`

```
<location path="SomeDir/SomeSubDir">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <deny users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

How do I change this so that this rule only applies when the app is not running on localhost? Is there a way to make the rule detect the environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would remove the deny from the web.config and use something like this in the page load event.

```
if(!HttpContext.Current.Request.IsLocal && !User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
```

Answer (score 0):

Config Transformations will give you a Web.Release.config that will transform your Web.Config when you publish with the Release settings.

If you don't already have the transform files, you will need to right-click the Web.config file and then click Add Config Transforms.

Here is the MSDN [How to: Transform Web.config When Deploying a Web Application Project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd465318%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Your Web.Release.config file would look something like this:

```
<configuration xmlns:xdt="...">
    <location xdt:Locator="Match(path)" xdt:Transform="Remove" />
</configuration>
```

Which will result in that location element being removed when you do a Release publish.